# Getting an error in Spark SQL although it can print the SQL and it can run through Hive

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I can print the SQL and it can run through Hive, but I get an error in Spark SQL.

```
  Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException: 
    mismatched input 'from' expecting {<EOF>, 'WHERE', 'GROUP', 'ORDER', 'HAVING', 'LIMIT', 'LATERAL', 'WINDOW', 'UNION', 'EXCEPT', 'MINUS', 'INTERSECT', 'SORT', 'CLUSTER', 'DISTRIBUTE'}(line 3, pos 11)

== SQL ==

           INSERT OVERWRITE  table zytrain.archer_odm_cate_info partition(data_date='20190227')
select u.* from
-----------^^^
(SELECT
t.cat_level1_name,t.cat_level1_id,
       t.cat_level2_name,t.goods_type,
       COUNT(t.goods_id) goods_cnt,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN t.sales_volume > 0 THEN t.goods_id END) saled_goods_cnt,
       SUM(expo_pv) expo_pv,
       SUM(goods_click) goods_click,
       SUM(cart_click) cart_click,
       SUM(bill_cnt) bill_cnt,
       SUM(sales_volume) sales_volume,
       SUM(sales_amount) sales_amount,
       SUM(gross_profit) gross_profit
FROM (SELECT a.cat_level1_name,a.cat_level1_id,a.cat_level2_name,
             case when t1.goods_id is not null then 'IS_ODM' else 'BU_NEWIN' end goods_type,
             b.goods_id,
             SUM(b.expo_pv) expo_pv,
             SUM(b.goods_click) goods_click,
             SUM(b.cart_click) cart_click,
             SUM(b.cur_day_bill) bill_cnt,
             SUM(b.sales_volume) sales_volume,
             SUM(b.sales_amount) sales_amount,
             SUM(b.gross_profit) gross_profit
      FROM dim.dim_jc_goods a
        LEFT OUTER JOIN rpt.rpt_sum_goods_daily b
                     ON a.goods_id = b.goods_id
                    AND b.site_id = 600
                    AND b.data_date BETWEEN '20190212'
                    AND '20190227'
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
        (
        SELECT DISTINCT a3.goods_id
                         FROM JOLLY.WHO_product_pool a1,
                              jolly.who_esoloo_supplier a2,
                              dim.dim_jc_goods a3
                         WHERE a1.supp_code = a2.code
                         AND   a2.supplier_genre = 8
                         AND   from_unixtime(gmt_created,'yyyyMMdd') >= '20190212'
                         AND   from_unixtime(gmt_created,'yyyyMMdd') <= '20190227'
                         AND   substr(a3.first_on_sale_time,1,10) <= '2019-02-27'
                         AND   a1.goods_id > 0
                         AND   a1.goods_id = a3.goods_id
        ) t1 ON a.goods_id = t1.goods_id
      WHERE substr(a.first_on_sale_time,1,10) BETWEEN '2019-02-13' AND '2019-02-27'
      AND   substr(a.add_time,1,10) BETWEEN '2019-02-12' AND  '2019-02-27'
      AND   a.cat_level1_id IN (2,324,7574,7576)
      GROUP BY a.cat_level1_name,a.cat_level1_id,
               a.cat_level2_name,
               b.goods_id,case when t1.goods_id is not null then 'IS_ODM' else 'BU_NEWIN' end) t
GROUP BY t.cat_level1_name,t.cat_level1_id,
         thet.cat_level2_name,t.goods_type order by t.cat_level1_id,t.goods_type
union all
SELECT
t.cat_level1_name,t.cat_level1_id,
       t.cat_level2_name,t.goods_type,
       COUNT(t.goods_id) goods_cnt,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN t.sales_volume > 0 THEN t.goods_id END) saled_goods_cnt,
       SUM(expo_pv) expo_pv,
       SUM(goods_click) goods_click,
       SUM(cart_click) cart_click,
       SUM(bill_cnt) bill_cnt,
       SUM(sales_volume) sales_volume,
       SUM(sales_amount) sales_amount,
       SUM(gross_profit) gross_profit
FROM (SELECT a.cat_level1_name,a.cat_level1_id,a.cat_level2_name,
             'BU_ALL' goods_type,
             b.goods_id,
             SUM(b.expo_pv) expo_pv,
             SUM(b.goods_click) goods_click,
             SUM(b.cart_click) cart_click,
             SUM(b.cur_day_bill) bill_cnt,
             SUM(b.sales_volume) sales_volume,
             SUM(b.sales_amount) sales_amount,
             SUM(b.gross_profit) gross_profit
      FROM dim.dim_jc_goods a
        LEFT OUTER JOIN rpt.rpt_sum_goods_daily b
                     ON a.goods_id = b.goods_id
                    AND b.site_id = 600
                    AND b.data_date BETWEEN '20190212'
                    AND '20190227'
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
        (
        SELECT DISTINCT a3.goods_id
                         FROM JOLLY.WHO_product_pool a1,
                              jolly.who_esoloo_supplier a2,
                              dim.dim_jc_goods a3
                         WHERE a1.supp_code = a2.code
                         AND   a2.supplier_genre = 8
                         AND   from_unixtime(gmt_created,'yyyyMMdd') >= '20190212'
                         AND   from_unixtime(gmt_created,'yyyyMMdd') <= '20190227'
                         AND   substr(a3.first_on_sale_time,1,10) <= '2019-02-27'
                         AND   a1.goods_id > 0
                         AND   a1.goods_id = a3.goods_id
        ) t1 ON a.goods_id = t1.goods_id
      WHERE
      t1.goods_id is null
      AND   a.cat_level1_id IN (2,324,7574,7576)
      GROUP BY a.cat_level1_name,a.cat_level1_id,
               a.cat_level2_name,
               b.goods_id) t
GROUP BY t.cat_level1_name,t.cat_level1_id,
         t.cat_level2_name,t.goods_type order by t.cat_level1_id,t.goods_type) u
```

Error output:

```
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException.withCommand(ParseDriver.scala:197)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AbstractSqlParser.parse(ParseDriver.scala:99)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkSqlParser.parse(SparkSqlParser.scala:45)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AbstractSqlParser.parsePlan(ParseDriver.scala:53)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:592)
at com.ODM.odm_info$.main(odm_info.scala:163)
at com.ODM.odm_info.main(odm_info.scala)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:743)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:187)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:212)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:126)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

Comment: my spark version is 2.1.1

Comment: do you need the partition(<values>). Also The dynamic partition columns must be specified last among the columns in the SELECT statement and in the same order in which they appear in the PARTITION() clause.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
val data1=spark.sql(
      s"""
         |SELECT
         |t.cat_level1_name,t.cat_level1_id,
         |       t.cat_level2_name,t.goods_type,
         |       COUNT(t.goods_id) goods_cnt,
         |       COUNT(CASE WHEN t.sales_volume > 0 THEN t.goods_id END) saled_goods_cnt,
         |       SUM(expo_pv) expo_pv,
         |       SUM(goods_click) goods_click,
         |       SUM(cart_click) cart_click,
         |       SUM(bill_cnt) bill_cnt,
         |       SUM(sales_volume) sales_volume,
         |       SUM(sales_amount) sales_amount,
         |       SUM(gross_profit) gross_profit
         |FROM (SELECT a.cat_level1_name,a.cat_level1_id,a.cat_level2_name,
         |             case when t1.goods_id is not null then 'IS_ODM' else 'BU_NEWIN' end goods_type,
         |             b.goods_id,
         |             SUM(b.expo_pv) expo_pv,
         |             SUM(b.goods_click) goods_click,
         |             SUM(b.cart_click) cart_click,
         |             SUM(b.cur_day_bill) bill_cnt,
         |             SUM(b.sales_volume) sales_volume,
         |             SUM(b.sales_amount) sales_amount,
         |             SUM(b.gross_profit) gross_profit
         |      FROM dim.dim_jc_goods a
         |        LEFT OUTER JOIN rpt.rpt_sum_goods_daily b
         |                     ON a.goods_id = b.goods_id
         |                    AND b.site_id = 600
         |                    AND b.data_date BETWEEN '20190212'
         |                    AND '$v_date1'
         |        LEFT OUTER JOIN
         |        (
         |        SELECT DISTINCT a3.goods_id
         |                         FROM JOLLY.WHO_product_pool a1,
         |                              jolly.who_esoloo_supplier a2,
         |                              dim.dim_jc_goods a3
         |                         WHERE a1.supp_code = a2.code
         |                         AND   a2.supplier_genre = 8
         |                         AND   from_unixtime(gmt_created,'yyyyMMdd') >= '20190212'
         |                         AND   from_unixtime(gmt_created,'yyyyMMdd') <= '$v_date1'
         |                         AND   substr(a3.first_on_sale_time,1,10) <= '$v_date2'
         |                         AND   a1.goods_id > 0
         |                         AND   a1.goods_id = a3.goods_id
         |        ) t1 ON a.goods_id = t1.goods_id
         |      WHERE substr(a.first_on_sale_time,1,10) BETWEEN '2019-02-13' AND '$v_date2'
         |      AND   substr(a.add_time,1,10) BETWEEN '2019-02-12' AND  '$v_date2'
         |      AND   a.cat_level1_id IN (2,324,7574,7576)
         |      GROUP BY a.cat_level1_name,a.cat_level1_id,
         |               a.cat_level2_name,
         |               b.goods_id,case when t1.goods_id is not null then 'IS_ODM' else 'BU_NEWIN' end) t
         |GROUP BY t.cat_level1_name,t.cat_level1_id,
         |         t.cat_level2_name,t.goods_type order by t.cat_level1_id,t.goods_type
       """.stripMargin).cache()
     val data_2=spark
      .sql(
        s"""
           |SELECT
           |t.cat_level1_name,t.cat_level1_id,
           |       t.cat_level2_name,t.goods_type,
           |       COUNT(t.goods_id) goods_cnt,
           |       COUNT(CASE WHEN t.sales_volume > 0 THEN t.goods_id END) saled_goods_cnt,
           |       SUM(expo_pv) expo_pv,
           |       SUM(goods_click) goods_click,
           |       SUM(cart_click) cart_click,
           |       SUM(bill_cnt) bill_cnt,
           |       SUM(sales_volume) sales_volume,
           |       SUM(sales_amount) sales_amount,
           |       SUM(gross_profit) gross_profit
           |FROM (SELECT a.cat_level1_name,a.cat_level1_id,a.cat_level2_name,
           |             'BU_ALL' goods_type,
           |             b.goods_id,
           |             SUM(b.expo_pv) expo_pv,
           |             SUM(b.goods_click) goods_click,
           |             SUM(b.cart_click) cart_click,
           |             SUM(b.cur_day_bill) bill_cnt,
           |             SUM(b.sales_volume) sales_volume,
           |             SUM(b.sales_amount) sales_amount,
           |             SUM(b.gross_profit) gross_profit
           |      FROM dim.dim_jc_goods a
           |        LEFT OUTER JOIN rpt.rpt_sum_goods_daily b
           |                     ON a.goods_id = b.goods_id
           |                    AND b.site_id = 600
           |                    AND b.data_date BETWEEN '20190212'
           |                    AND '$v_date1'
           |        LEFT OUTER JOIN
           |        (
           |        SELECT DISTINCT a3.goods_id
           |                         FROM JOLLY.WHO_product_pool a1,
           |                              jolly.who_esoloo_supplier a2,
           |                              dim.dim_jc_goods a3
           |                         WHERE a1.supp_code = a2.code
           |                         AND   a2.supplier_genre = 8
           |                         AND   from_unixtime(gmt_created,'yyyyMMdd') >= '20190212'
           |                         AND   from_unixtime(gmt_created,'yyyyMMdd') <= '$v_date1'
           |                         AND   substr(a3.first_on_sale_time,1,10) <= '$v_date2'
           |                         AND   a1.goods_id > 0
           |                         AND   a1.goods_id = a3.goods_id
           |        ) t1 ON a.goods_id = t1.goods_id
           |      WHERE
           |      t1.goods_id is null
           |      AND   a.cat_level1_id IN (2,324,7574,7576)
           |      GROUP BY a.cat_level1_name,a.cat_level1_id,
           |               a.cat_level2_name,
           |               b.goods_id) t
           |GROUP BY t.cat_level1_name,t.cat_level1_id,
           |         t.cat_level2_name,t.goods_type order by t.cat_level1_id,t.goods_type
         """.stripMargin).cache()
    val data_3=data1.union(data_2)
    data_3.createOrReplaceTempView("data_3")
    spark.sql(
      s"""
         | INSERT OVERWRITE  table zytrain.archer_odm_cate_info partition(data_date='$v_date1')
         | select * from data_3
       """.stripMargin)
    println("end")
```